# Oracle spatial - check polygon vertices counter clockwise

Tags: spatial-database, java, oracle-spatial

I need to import a huge number of polygons from a third party (as a csv file- array of x,y's).  I have to check whether the polygon vertices are in clockwise or counter clockwise, finally i have to convert it into counter clockwise and store it in the oracle spatial table as sdo geometry.

I am not able to find any oracle spatial java API to check the array of vertices and convert it into counter clockwise.  I tried the same question in oracle spatial forum, but they said no API for this.

do you have ever worked on this oracle spatial java API, any other thoughts.  ( i have found some methods to validate the ring rotation "http://paulbourke.net/geometry/clockwise/index.html", but if it is from oracle it will be good to implement).

Comment: Run SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_objgeom.htm#BGHFDDBF returns The context of the error (the coordinate, edge, or ring that causes the geometry to be invalid)

Comment: I would be good, if it is in java api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXECUTE SDO_MIGRATE.TO_CURRENT('YOUR_TABLE');
Should correct the orientation of your polygons (10G r2)

Comment: I have got the logic to check the polygon geometry before storing into database    http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=geometry2

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is ancient, but for anyone else wondering about this scenario:

Maybe the steps would be:

1. In a query, validate the polygons using `sdo_geom.validate_geometry_with_context()`.

   - Related: [Look up SDO_GEOMETRY validation error code using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548957/look-up-sdo-geometry-validation-error-code-using-sql)
2. For the polygons that have problems, use the `rectify_geometry()` function to fix them (within a query).
3. Store all the polygons (including the rectified polygons) in the final Oracle table as SDO_GEOMETRY.

That's just a guess. I'm not an Oracle Spatial expert.

I know the question asked for a Java solution, and this proposed solution isn't Java. But maybe it's possible to put the data in a temporary db table somewhere, run the SQL queries on it as I suggested, and then INSERT the resulting data into the final table. **Maybe it's possible to run those SQL queries from Java code?** (execute SQL from within Java)

Or maybe there is a way to use some sort of Oracle DB tool to load the CSV into a temporary table, and then proceed from there?

Or maybe just use a GIS tool like ArcGIS Pro to import the CSV into a temporary Oracle/SDO_GEOMETRY table. Maybe ArcGIS Pro would automatically rectify any problem polygons. Now that I think about it more, I think I like this idea best. Rectifying and loading GIS data is what GIS tools like ArcGIS Pro are good at.

Just some uneducated thoughts.