# Missing holes after exporting GeoJSON in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, bing-maps

I don't know if this is QGIS related. I am trying to export a GeoJSON from a vector layer in QGIS.

The problem is visualising the vector in Bing map. The shape is missing
some holes, as it should be.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this is related to the order in which vertices are stored for interior rings versus exterior polygon boundaries. Some reading on the topic: https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils/issues/7 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119150/order-of-polygon-vertices-in-general-gis-clockwise-or-counterclockwise

Comment: What does your question have to do with QGIS canvas size?